# Get the total of multiple column in sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

In database I have such table:

```
| id  hotel_id | room_id | Ac_rooms | Non_ac_rooms | simple_rooms | Furnitured_room | other_rooms | added_by  |
| 9            |     2   |      3   |       2       |      6      |       12        |      21      |      raj  |
```

I want to get the total numbers of room from SQL query (which is the total of room_id, Ac_rooms, Non_ac_rooms, simple_rooms, Furnitured_room, other_rooms).

What is the best way to get the total from SQL query? I need total number of rows.

Comment: `Select Ac_rooms + Non_ac_rooms + simple_rooms + Furnitured_room + other_rooms as  TotalRooms`

Comment: Try : select (ac_rooms + Non_ac_rooms + simple_rooms + Furnitured_room + other_rooms) as total from table_name Order by hotel_id

Comment: i need a function which return the total no of count (Ac_rooms | Non_ac_rooms | simple_rooms | Furnitured_room | other_rooms) like 10 in result.

Comment: select (sum(ac_rooms ) + sum(Non_ac_rooms) + sum(simple_rooms) + sum(Furnitured_room) + sum(other_rooms)) from YOUR_TABLE

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor design. And 'room_id+' ?? How does that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
SUM(Ac_rooms) as Ac_rooms,
SUM(Non_ac_rooms) as Non_ac_rooms,
SUM(Simple_rooms) as Simple_rooms,
SUM(Furnitured_rooms) as Furnitured_room,
SUM(Other_rooms) as Other_rooms,
SUM(Ac_rooms+Non_ac_rooms+Simple_rooms+Furnitured_room+Other_rooms) as Total_rooms,
FROM tbl_rooms
```

Or

```
SELECT
SUM(SUM(Ac_rooms)+SUM(Non_ac_rooms)+SUM(Simple_rooms)+SUM(Furnitured_room)+SUM(Other_rooms)) as Total_rooms,
FROM tbl_rooms
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you just need the sum

```
select (ac_rooms + Non_ac_rooms + simple_rooms + Furnitured_room + other_rooms) as total_rooms from YOUR_TABLE
```

Also you specified finding total number of rows, which you can get by using standart `count` function

```
select count(*) as number_of_rows from YOUR_TABLE
```

Or may be you are looking for the sum of types of the rooms through all the rows? In that case you will need

```
select sum(ac_rooms ), sum(Non_ac_rooms), sum(simple_rooms), sum(Furnitured_room), sum(other_rooms) from YOUR_TABLE
```

UPD: If I got you right, you need this

```
select sum(ac_rooms ) as ac_rooms_total,
       sum(Non_ac_rooms) as non_ac_rooms_total,
       sum(simple_rooms) as simple_rooms_total,
       sum(Furnitured_room) as furnitured_room_total,
       sum(other_rooms) as other_rooms_total,
       sum(ac_rooms + Non_ac_rooms + simple_rooms + Furnitured_room + other_rooms) as TOTAL
from YOUR_TABLE
```

Comment: @Arushi could you elaborate on more details on what exactly do you need?

Comment: i need a function which return the total no of count (Ac_rooms | Non_ac_rooms | simple_rooms | Furnitured_room | other_rooms) like 10 in result.

Comment: @Arushi I have updated the answer is that what you need?